# printing string into command line like it's a new command

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, printing

I want to make a shortcut for long commands with default arguments so I can bring the command into the command line and then add or change arguments by myself.

For example with the command `wget`:

```
print "wget -O downloaded.file"
```

will result in:

```
user@hostname$ wget -O downloaded.file
```

and then I add the "url" I want to download from:

```
user@hostname$ wget -O downloaded.file http://example.com/
```

Comment: I suggest to use an alias (`help alias`) or a function (`help function`).

Comment: @DanielZabelin You explained additional requirements in a comment to the answer. Please [edit] your question and add all requirements there. Add an example that shows a more difficult use case, i.e. editing arguments instead of only appending arguments. Did you consider using the command history? You can search for a previous command and edit it as you like. If you cannot use this, please explain why.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
alias my_personal_wget_shortcut="wget -O downloaded.file"
```

additional arguments are added afterwards:

```
my_personal_wget_shortcut http://example.com/
```

With a function or a shell script, you can place the arguments anywhere you like:

Function:

```
my_personal_wget_shortcut()
{
    wget -O downloaded.file "$@"
}
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -O downloaded.file "$@"
```

Don't forget to set the x-bit on the script!

Comment: It is advisable to use a shortcut that is shorter than the replacement.

Comment: thank you for your answer but its one of the solutions I already tried and it doesn't cover my problem. I use long commands for automating tasks and one of the reasons I want it to print straight to my command line is because I want to add default arguments and then change them if I need to.

Comment: @DanielZabelin : Why does my solution not cover this application? If you do a `alias w= -O downloaded.file`, you can then do a `w add any argument you want`. I personally would prefer a function over an alias for various reasons, but an alias would work just fine.

Comment: @user1934428 as I said, I want to use default arguments for the commands that I can change easily and some of the arguments are including arrays, files,integers or just basic flags so it would be much more difficult to change them within a script / function / other alias.

Comment: I see. Then do it as a function or a script, not as an alias. The example in your question only shows adding arguments. If you have trouble defining default arguments for a script, I suggest that you make a new question for this. It is a new problem and deserves its own discussion, as there are several ways to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on solutions from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82716/330217 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325220/330217.

You might also get some ideas from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391698/330217

---

Clean way  for `bash`, but requires pressing cursor-up:

You can put "fake" commands onto `bash`'s command history using

```
history -s 'some command'
```

(see https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-History-Builtins)

After putting the command to the history you can press the cursor-up key to get this command into the command buffer and edit it as you like.

Of course you can use an alias as a shortcut.

```
alias myalias="history -s 'wget -O downloaded.file '"

myalias
```

After pressing cursor-up you should get

```
wget -O downloaded.file _
```

Note: The underscore (`_`) is meant to show the cursor position after the trailing space.

---

More hacky solution which directly fills the command buffer:

```
writecmd () { 
  perl -e 'ioctl STDOUT, 0x5412, $_ for split //, do{ chomp($_ = <>); $_ }' ; 
}

# Example usage
echo 'my test cmd' | writecmd
```

Combined with an alias

```
writecmd () { 
  perl -e 'ioctl STDOUT, 0x5412, $_ for split //, do{ chomp($_ = <>); $_ }' ; 
}

alias myalias="echo 'wget -O downloaded.file '|writecmd"

myalias
```

should directly result in

```
wget -O downloaded.file _
```

**Note: This solution has the drawback that it also prints the command to stdout. That means the command also appears before the prompt.** (I don't know if it is possible to suppress this. When I redirect stdout to `/dev/null`, the command will no longer be written to the command buffer.)

---

In `zsh` you could use `print -z` to put something into the command buffer.

```
alias myalias="print -z 'wget -O downloaded.file '"
```

Comment: Thx! the zsh way works like I need but I dont really use zsh and the perl way result in printing the string 2 times like this: `wget -O downloaded.file user@hostname$ wget -O downloaded.file`

Comment: @DanielZabelin I just highlighted the remark that states this drawback.